# want to set input value from variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

want to set a variable value to input box

```
success: function(result_email){
                    console.log(result_email);
                    ('#verify_email').val('asc');
                }
```

getting error like

```
user-registration.js:123 Uncaught TypeError: "#verify_email".val is not a function
at Object.success (user-registration.js:123)
```

Comment: Can you please share your AJAX code?

Comment: Also are you using json_encode to pass the data?

Comment: i am getting email value in result_email variable

Comment: its like abc@m.com

Comment: Try `$('#verify_email').val('asc')`.

Comment: yes i tried but its giving same error

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$('#verify_email').val(result_email);
```

Comment: got ya forgot to add $ so thats why